# Using RESTful server for sending message to client in Unity

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, unity-game-engine

We are using a RESTful Microsoft Web.API for server side and Unity for client for a poker game.

Is there any way to get updates from server about changes in game (chat messages and a new play moves inside the current poker room)?

We consider of using Keep Alive messages like:

```
private string m_URL = "ADDRESS";
private string results;

IEnumerator Start () {
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(m_URL))
    {
        yield return www.Send();

        if (www.isError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            results = www.downloadHandler.text;
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
void Update()
{ 
    StartCoroutine(Start());
}
```

But I dont think that's is the best option and probably going to send hundred of messages to the server

Comment: Web api should be stateless so you really should not do this. For two way communication you can use SignalR or just WebSockets. [Age of ascent](https://www.ageofascent.com/blog/) has some dev resources on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I just wonder to know, how does my "Solution" impact the stateless status of my web api server? thanks.

Comment: Sorry after rereading your question what do you mean by " Keep Alive " messages. At first I thought you were talking about Long pulling but now I don't know how you were planning to use it to send messages to the client.

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear enough, what I mean in Keep Alive is just sending get request in every X time to the server for get the updates

Comment: Ok I get what you want to do. Unlike long pulling this solution will not be state full BUT I still stand by the websockets with or without SignalR recommendation that is by far the best way of doing it.